# Current through resistors crossing each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

[image: Resistors combination]

Calculate the current shown by the ammeter A in the given circuit. I've searched the internet but didn't know how to search for it. Please help

Comment: Because of symmetry in the circuit, you can split the junction in the middle along vertical axis. Then, it becomes a simple series-parallel combination.

Comment: @ShankRam can you please explain with the help of a diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is the simplified ckt.. Now, use series parallel combination to solve for current.

Comment: No problem. We are here to help each other out right? ;)